# How to replace OpenExeConfiguration in a web context (asp.net mvc 1)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

OK so we have something that is currently using OpenExeConfiguration for reading a config file, however this doesn't work when running in the web context.

I've tried a variety of different ways of opening the web.config programmatically but I can't seem to get it to read the correct web.config file. In case it matters I am currently debugging it in VS 2008.

```
1. config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);

2. config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "web.config" }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

3. config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

4. config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);

5.  System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
```

It either opens up the wrong config file (either the machine config, or the VS /IDE/Web.config) or complains about the error:

{System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.

**Edit -** 
OK so a combination of

```
config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

AND running Visual Studio 2008 As Administrator worked.  Am hoping we don't run into security/permission issues when we deploy to our web server / client environments!

Comment: Are you using the built in web server or a real IIS one? the built in one does somethings differently, as you've found out.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the built in web server whilst developing.  It's annoying because as I discovered this morning if I forget to run Visual Studio as Administrator then I get errors (computer must have rebooted after an update).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So in the end I used this code (had to handle whether the web application was running, or if our unit test code was running).

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = null;

if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null && !System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath.Equals(string.Empty))
        config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
else
        config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Also have to be running Visual Studio in Administrator mode - which I found out you can set as a property on your shortcut so you don't need to remember each time in Windows 7 to right click and run as administrator :)

Comment: `&& !System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath.Equals(string.Empty))` is not required