# Modify SmtpSection in web.config in c# code in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, web-config, smtp

I have set up the following in my web.config to have multiple smtp settings defined:

```
    <sectionGroup name="mailSettings">
      <section name="smtp_1" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="smtp_2" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp_1 deliveryMethod="Network" from="xxx@hotmail.com">
      <network host="smtp.live.com" port="587" userName="xxx@hotmail.com" password="xxx" defaultCredentials="false"/>
    </smtp_1>
    <smtp_2 deliveryMethod="Network" from="yyy@gmail.com">
      <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465" userName="yyy@gmail.com" password="yyy" defaultCredentials="false"/>
    </smtp_2>
  </mailSettings>
```

I have been able to retrieve any of the settings using code and I have set up a function to iterate through the config file and pull out each smtp setting and add to a dropdownlist.

The only thing that doesn't want to work is actually writing back to the web.config (either adding a new smtp or modifying an existing one). I have used the following C# code:

```
    Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    SmtpSection smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("mailSettings/smtp_1");
    smtpSection.From = "zzz@hotmail.com";
    smtpSection.Network.Port = 25;
    smtpSection.Network.UserName = "xxx";
    smtpSection.Network.Password = "xxx";
    webConfig.Save();
```

But this returns the error: 
**The configuration is read only.**

This code works perfectly fine, but of course it modifies the primary smtp settings in the system.net (where you cannot have multiple smtp settings).

```
    System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSection = webConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup;
    mailSection.Smtp.From = "xxx@hotmail.com";
    mailSection.Smtp.Network.Host = "smtp.live.com";
    mailSection.Smtp.Network.Port = 25;
    webConfig.Save();
```

Been racking my brain over this and can't seem to find the answer. Feels like it's going to be something so simple (or just not possible). If not, will probably need to encrypt settings and store in the DB.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Writing to the `web.config` is just not a good idea. Can't you write the settings to Database for example ?

Comment: I agree with dimitar smtpsettings would be placed better in a db table

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. Initially I wanted to write straight to the DB but after further research it looked as if writing to web.config and encrypting was the *better* way to go.

Comment: Yes. This works:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629209/how-to-replace-openexeconfiguration-in-a-web-context-asp-net-mvc-1