# Connect to a web service using a mapped configuration file

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asynchronous, configuration

We have a CRM2011 plugin running async which needs to connect to a webservice to get some missing data. The way i'm trying to solve this is to use a webservice client, made using 'add service reference'.

But for configuration i don't want to hard code the endpoint and binding. So i thought i would just load the configuration for the webservice using `OpenMappedExeConfiguration` like so.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap{ ExeConfigFilename = @"c:\Path\to\config.xml"}, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

The config file is loaded... however it is not visible to the client. Because calling

```
var client = new MyDataServiceClient();
```

will throw

> InvalidOperationException :
>
> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 
>   'MyDataService.IMyDataService' in the ServiceModel client 
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file 
>   was found for your application, or because no endpoint element 
>   matching this contract could be found in the client element.

The configuration file i'm using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyDataService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint
        address="https://integrationservices-dev.thecompany.com/MyDataService/MyDataService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyDataService"
        contract="MyDataService.IMyDataService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyDataService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I know i could initialize a binding and endpoint and give those to the `MyDataServiceClient(Binding, Endpoint)` constructor. But i rather don't want to write my own configuration loader logic.

Is there a way to make the loaded config known to the code constructing the client? If not what other options are there ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a exe configuration but you are on Web Context, I think you must use `OpenWebConfiguration`.

In short this command opens the Web-application configuration file as a Configuration object.

Alternatively you can add your configuration into **web.config** on CRM site

See [this Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629209/how-to-replace-openexeconfiguration-in-a-web-context-asp-net-mvc-1)

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.openwebconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The plugin is running async. And i believe it would be executed using the MSCRM Async processing service, which is a windows service.

Comment: I will discuss at our company wether or not we will alter the crm config file(s). The thing is that imho the configuration belongs to the plugin and would best be kept in a plugin settings entity. Also we have multiple tenants and we may have to deal with multiple services eventually.

Comment: I've updated your question with the async info. In your scenario I think is better to use a class constructor with URL parameter.

Comment: After some debating here. The plugin is meant to be generic in nature and should be able to run depending on how the plugin is registered. So both sync and async are possible.